# Store in array with some spaces

Tags: c, memcpy

I have a problem using `memcpy()`.

I have an array of 36 bytes. the first 20 should be filled with mobile number and the other 16 with voucher number. If mobile number is less then 20 then it should be filled with spaces. But when I fill voucher number it overrides the first value. Below is my code.

```
char tempMobileNo[20],tempVoucherNo[16],o2RecordData[50];
memset(tempMobileNo,' ',20);
memset(tempVoucherNo,' ',16);
memset(o2RecordData,' ',RECORD_DATA_L);         
memcpy(tempMobileNo,ValueB,20);       
memcpy(tempVoucherNo,ValueC,16);        
memcpy(&o2RecordData[0],tempMobileNo,20);
memcpy(&o2RecordData[22],tempVoucherNo,16);
```

Comment: There's something fishy with your last line of code. You've previously defined tempVoucherNo to be a 16 chars array. Now you're copying 22 bytes from it ...

Comment: What I find suspicious is that you are filling with spaces... but you're doing nothing with the end-of-string markers (`'\0'`)... might be not needed as you're copying `ValueB` and `ValueC` completely. Could you provide the code where you see that the voucher overrides the mobile number?. Could you provide the definition of o2RecordData, ValueB and ValueC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

**`memcpy`** is implemented in such way that you will **always** copy the number of specified bytes, it doesn't know if the "contents" of a buffer ends earlier and whether it shall stop copying because of this, nor does it care.

Since you first fill you buffers with spaces, but then **unconditionally** copy the length specified nto the buffer in (*A*) and (*B*), your spaces will be "overwritten" by whatever 20 and 16 bytes, respectively, available in *Valueb* and *ValueC*.

```
 memcpy(tempMobileNo,  ValueB, 20); // (A)      
 memcpy(tempVoucherNo, ValueC, 16); // (B)
```

---

#### Thoughts

If you are dealing with *c-style strings* (ie. null-terminated strings), consider using **`strncpy`** instead of **`memcpy`**.

**`strncpy (dst, src, n)`** will copy at most **`n`** characters, unless it hits the end of **`src`** (a null-byte).

Comment: what if my valueB is not of 20 bytes and I want to add the spaces

Comment: I did use strcpy but the result was the same :(

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar Note that `strcpy` will copy the null-byte from *src* to *dst*, this will effectively end *tempVoucherNo* and *tempMobileNo* prematurely. You will need to replace the null-byte with a space after copying, and make sure you null-terminate both arrays prior to using them as *c-style strings*.

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>**Note**: this post was created prior to OP editing his question, it's no longer of relevance.</sup>

---

```
memcpy(&o2RecordData[22],tempVoucherNo,22);
```

should be

```
memcpy(&o2RecordData[20],tempVoucherNo,16);
```

Comment: memcpy(&o2RecordData[22],tempVoucherNo,22);
this will add at 22nd index.

Comment: at the 23rd index. but you want to start at the 21st index

Comment: **-1**: This is not the direct problem with the code, see my post for why.